# Timed MessageBox python

Tags: python, user-interface, messagebox

How can I create a MessageBox (like in the example) in python and close it from the code after a few seconds?

```
m= win32gui.MessageBox(None,data, "SnapShot", 0x00000000L) #creating a messagebox with the message and OK button
```

Comment: Try `int,int = SendMessageTimeout(hwnd, message , wparam , lparam , flags , timeout )`or setup a `threading.Timer(...` to close.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimer` function from Win32 API to register a function to be executed after some milliseconds ; in the registered function, close the dialog box. For example, here is the code to close the dialog after 1 second:

```
from win32 import timer as w32timer

def close_messagebox(*args):
  m.close()

w32timer.setTimer(1000, close_messagebox)
```

(untested code)

Other approaches like using Python's `sched` module or `threading` do not work because the dialog has to be closed from the main thread. The idea with a Windows timer is to make the event happening in the events loop.